# Vector Layer not displayed properly in 3D

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, remote-sensing, 3d, 3d-map

I am using Qgis2threejs plugin to display my map in 3D. But I am facing a problem in displaying vector layer properly. Please look at the following image.Buildings are not displayed according to DEM. it looks like they are floating in the air. Also Roads and Buildings are distorted from their original places. How to fix this? Can someone help?   [image]

Comment: Do you have the building set at an z-value so that it 'stands' on your DEM? If not the program just thinks the buildings should start at z = 0. I think this goes the same for your roads. Do all of your layers have the same CRS?